# Looping over an array that consists of associate arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[

   {
    "positional_index":"1.3",
    "sourceid":10409,
    "language": "Malayalam",
    "field_gita_10409_text": "Behold, O Teacher! this mighty army of the sons of Pandu, arrayed by the son of Drupada, thy wise disciple."


   },

   {
    "positional_index":"1.2",
    "sourceid":10409,
    "language": "Devanagari",
    "field_gita_10409_text": "1.1 Dhritarashtra said What did my people and the sons of Pandu do when they had assembled together eager for battle on the holy plain of Kurukshetra, O Sanjaya."



   },
]
```

I am supposed to use a foreach loop to access each of the keys. For example if the key = field_gita_10409_text, I have to used the explode() function in php to extract the value 10409 etc.

I don't know how to use the foreach loop in this case, because the array consists 2 associative arrays. Please let me know.

Comment: Isn't your field `sourceid` always the number your after - `10409` in this case.

Comment: Is that an array? Please edit your question and paste the code you are using

Comment: can you clarify what output you are expecting ?

Comment: Actually this is NOT arrays within arrays. It is an array of _objects_ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop inside your loop:

```
foreach ($array as $item){
        foreach ($item as $key=>$value){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need inner loop to get keys and values.

```
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach ($array as $innerArray){
        foreach ($innerArray as $key=>$value){
            if($key == 'field_gita_10409_text'){
              $exp = explode($value);
            }
        }
    }
```